# R - sql query stored as object name does not work with r dbGetquery

Tags: r

Need a little help with the following R code. I’ve got quite a number of data to load from a Microsoft sql database. I tried to do a few things to make the sql queries manageable.

1) Stored the query as object names with unique prefix
2) Using search to return a vector of the object names with unique prefix
3) using for loop to loop through the vector to load data <- this part didn’t work.

```
Library(odbc)
Library(tidyverse)
Library(stringer)

#setting up dB connection, odbc pkg
db<- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),Driver =‘SQL Server’, Server=‘Server_name’, Database=‘Datbase name’, UID=‘User ID’, trusted_connection=‘yes’)

#defining the sql query
Sql_query1<-“select * from db1”
Sql_query2<-“select top 100 * from db2”

#the following is to store the sql query object name in a vector by searching for object names with prefix sql_
Sql_list <- ls()[str_detect(ls(),regex(“sql_”,ignore_case=TRUE))]

#This is the part where the code didn’t work
For (i in Sql_list){ i <- dbGetQuery(db, i)}
```

The error I’ve got is “Error:  ‘Sql_query1’ nanodb.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure ‘Sql_query1’

However, if i don’t use the loop, no error occurred! It may be feasible if I’ve only got 2 -3 queries to manage... unfortunately I’ve 20 of them!

```
dbGetquery(db,Sql_query1)
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: You have strange double and single quotes in code. Please fix here and maybe in actual code.

Comment: Two solutions. 1: Use `dbGetQuery(db, get(i))` instead of `dbGetQuery(db, i)` to get the result you want. 2: Store the queries in an array and avoid all of this nonsense

Comment: I'd very much support second solution of @Rohit. Having these queries in a list will make your code much more elegant and not clutter your workspace. Then you can use `lapply`, `sapply` or one the `purrr::map` variations to run all queries without a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions and answers! I’ve learned more than the question I’ve asked itself. I’m still picking up on this language. Will give purrr::map a try after reading up a little bit more. Thank you so much once again to all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rohits solution written down:
first part from your side is fine

```
#setting up dB connection, odbc pkg   
db<- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),Driver =‘SQL Server’, Server=‘Server_name’, Database=‘Datbase name’, UID=‘User ID’, trusted_connection=‘yes’)
```

But then it would be more convenient to do something like this:
A more verbose version:

```
sqlqry_lst <- vector(mode = 'list', length = 2)#create a list to hold queries the in real life length = 20
names(sqlqry_lst) <- paste0('Sql_query', 1:2)#assign names to your list again jut use 1:20 here in your real life example
#put the SQL code into the list elements 
sqlqry_lst['Sql_query1'] <- "select * from db1" 
sqlqry_lst['Sql_query2'] <- "select top 100 * from db2"
#if you really want to use for loops
res <- vector(mode = 'list', length(sqlqry_lst))#result list 
for (i in length(sqlqry_lst)) res[[i]] <- dbGetquery(db,sqlqry_lst[[i]])
```

Or as a two liner, a bit more R stylish and imho elegant:

```
sqlqry_lst <- list(Sql_query1="select * from db1", Sql_query2="select top 100 * from db2") 
res <- lapply(sqlqry_lst, FUN = dbGetQuery, conn=db)
```

I suggest you mix and mingle the verbose eg for creating or more precisely for naming the query list and the short version for running the queries against the database as it suits u best.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m still picking up on this language and hearing all these suggestions is FANTASTIC!!